Testlink 'My settings' page is not opening
I am trying to open my settings page on testlink but following error it shows on browser
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: sizeof(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, null given in C:\Apache24\htdocs\testlink-code-testlink_1_9_20_fixed\lib\functions\object.class.php:600 Stack trace: #0 C:\Apache24\htdocs\testlink-code-testlink_1_9_20_fixed\lib\functions\object.class.php(576): tlDBObject::createObjectsFromDB(Object(database), NULL, 'tlEvent', true, 4294967295) #1 C:\Apache24\htdocs\testlink-code-testlink_1_9_20_fixed\lib\functions\logger.class.php(679): tlDBObject::createObjectsFromDBbySQL(Object(database), 'SELECT E.id FRO...', 'id', 'tlEvent', true, 4294967295, 10) #2 C:\Apache24\htdocs\testlink-code-testlink_1_9_20_fixed\lib\functions\logger.class.php(123): tlEventManager->getEventsFor('16', '1', 'users', '('LOGIN_FAILED'...', 10, NULL, NULL, NULL) #3 C:\Apache24\htdocs\testlink-code-testlink_1_9_20_fixed\lib\usermanagement\userInfo.php(70): tlLogger->getAuditEventsFor('1', 'users', 'LOGIN_FAILED', 10) #4 {main} thrown in C:\Apache24\htdocs\testlink-code-testlink_1_9_20_fixed\lib\functions\object.class.php on line 600
i am using testlink 1.9.20. web server is apache24 and php version is PHP 8.3.7
Login as admin to test link created some test cases and want to get testlink API key for automation purpose.

This is my workaround:
Edit file lib/functions/database.class.php at line 595
replace
$items = null;
with
$items = array();
